# Permission for accesing external storage in android studio not showing after launch

Tags: java, android

I am building a small music player app but it wont request permission to read songs after launching

Permission request for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` not triggering in Android app despite correct implementation. Manifest includes permission, code for runtime permission check and request is correctly implemented in the activity, but the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method isn't being called after the permission dialog interaction.I have latest android studio version. How can i solve this issue?

This is my android vversion that im using:

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4

Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Android of used device: Android 14

This is my code

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);

        }else{

            //you have permission to read from external storage
            getSongs();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getSongs();
            }else{

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: changes added @blackapps

Comment: @blackapps sorry, its android 14

Comment: For Android 13+ devices you should not request this read permission. You have it by default in all public directories on external storage.